# error LGHT0204: ICE57: Component has both per-user and per-machine data with a per-machine KeyPath

Tags: wix, registry

Hi I get below error causing to fail the build but the Wix Installer MSI gets created in bin. How can i avoid these errors or suppress ?

error LGHT0204: ICE57: Component 'cmp52CD5A4CB5D668097543295CE11F998C' has both per-user and per-machine data with a per-machine KeyPath.

```
<Component Id="cmp52CD5A4CB5D668097543295CE11F998C" Directory="dir61E1488DA838A25DC7BC0F573A0FB3CD" Guid="*">
                <Class Id="{017F9D47-1C89-3448-8C8F-531717713535}" Context="InprocServer32" Description="ComponentArt.Web.UI.CustomAttributeMappingCollection" ThreadingModel="both" ForeignServer="mscoree.dll">
                    <ProgId Id="ComponentArt.Web.UI.CustomAttributeMappingCollection" Description="ComponentArt.Web.UI.CustomAttributeMappingCollection" />
                </Class>
```

Comment: Is your installer Per-Machine (ALLUSERS=1 or 2) If so, ignore this warning. IIRC, the ICE57 warning has a bug.

Comment: Yes it is per-Machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To address the warning go away, ensure that `dir61E1488DA838A25DC7BC0F573A0FB3CD` is rooted in a per-machine `Directory` such as `ProgramFilesFolder`.

Comment: What if the installation scoped to 'perUser' and I also had the TARGETDIR points to roaming folder